# Access project.json metadata via reflection?

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to access `project.json` metadata from a deployed application?

For example, in .NET 4.5 projects I would decorate my app like this

```
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("My App")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.5.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("Developer Build")]
```

and then at application startup, use reflection to read these values and write them to the log. The use case being that it is then easy to verify exactly what build is running in the wild.

Is it possible to reflect the `project.json` metadata instead? eg:

```
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"description": "My app - acme widget factory",
"authors": [ "gbshaw" ],
"tags": [ "widget acme" ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell (at least in Beta 6), the only `project.json` attribute that can be reflected is `version`.

Using the same project.json as specified in the question and then building the app with [`DNX_BUILD_VERSION`](http://nblumhardt.com/2015/07/set-the-asterisk-in-project-json-version-numbers/) set to `foobar` by my build server say, then ILSpy shows these attributes only

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.0.0-foobar")]
```

You can however still use the traditional assembly attributes. The `AssemblyVersion` and `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attributes will actually override `project.json version`.